# actionscript 2: pick 3 random nummers from array

Tags: random, actionscript

i need 3 random variables from array 0-36 (roulette). 
i have this code. script return first 3 nummers from random array. 
i need return 3 random nummers (from random position) from random array.
help me please.

```
onClipEvent (load) {

// field 0-36
var rands = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < 36; ++i)
{
  rands[i] = i;
}

// random sorting array
rands.sort(function(a,b) {return random(3)-1;});

// final variables 1,2,3
random1 = rands[0];
random2 = rands[1];
random3 = rands[2];
}
```

this is possible code for 1 variable, i need convert this to 3 variables in AS2

```
n = 3;
for (var i:Number = 0; i < n; i++) {
var randomSelection = Math.floor((Math.random() * rands.length));
trace("Selected: " + rands[randomSelection]);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question what you want, but this is my guess:

```
var n = 3;
var random = [];

for (var i:Number = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Store the random selections in an array
    random.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * rands.length));
}

// You could assign them to variables or access directly via array
var random1 = random[0];
var random2 = random[1];
var random3 = random[2];
```

Comment: thanks very much. very helpful for me. i am lama.
help me please with this:
**(select randomly 3 nummer from array [rands] and push to array [random], when the selected number exists in array[random], select another number)**

Comment: Best bet would be to ask another question.